# What does getting a prompt after creating a database mean?

Tags: mysql

Everywhere I look I can't find this "EXACT" situation.

I enter: `create database october24`

after hitting return I get:

```
->
```

So it's not my regular linux prompt and it's not the mysql prompt after logging in, which is `mysql>`

I don't get/see any errors just that crappy little prompt. I have to "ctrl-c" to get out, otherwise, nothing I enter after that prompt does squat. I haven't found anything on this. Can someone who is more versed in msyql/SQL point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end each statement with a semi-colon (`;`).

```
create database october24;
```

That prompt is because MySQL doesn't know you were done with your query and is expecting more input.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semi-colon. Type it, press enter and then the prompt will be back :)

EG:

```
mysql> select id, max(name)    
    -> from table
    -> group by id;
```